# What’s the difference between ‘such’ and ‘this’?

Tags: grammar

I was solving following problem. I had to fill in the blank with a right word.

Q) ... In your e-mail, you stated that the compartment does not close properly. _____ issue was brought up by other customers in the past. Our technicians ...
A) This
B) Their
C) The other
D) Such

I thought the answer was ‘Such’ as the meaning of ‘like’. This is because other customers also had similar problem in the past. However, my text says that the answer is ‘This’. I understand it also makes sense, but I don’t know what the difference is. Could you explain this please?

Comment: For an answer based on your own intuition, consider why you used *this* instead of *such* in the closing sentence of your question.

Comment: Exam questions may be off topic on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

I think that correct word is `This`.

1. Option D (`such`) is very different from the others.
2. The previous sentence contains `the compartment`, therefore it is clear that we talk about a very specific place where the problem occurs.
3. The issue is also very clear.
4. `Such` suggests a class of issues - but here we do not have a class of them, but only one, very specific.
5. Options B and C are obviously not suitable in any way here

> This is because other customers also had similar problem in the past.

Well, `This` / `Such` refers obviously to the issue, which is only one, not to the customers. The fact that the issue appeared more than one time is not relevant - it is just one issue.

Answer (score 0):

The results yielded by querying the iWeb Corpus indicate that 'such issue' is always used after 'no', 'one' or 'any'. examples: Rest assured, there is no such issue with your eBay account. There had been no such issue for weeks or months past. One such issue was that of gender testing in Olympic  athletes. One such issue is the presence of the naturally occurring protein avidin in raw egg whites. Bred in the constitutional tradition of my father, I should never have allowed any such issue to arise. He had diagnosed me with Social Phobia without discussing any such issue with me. The results also show that 'such an issue' is grammatically correct. examples: Not sure why that mod would cause such an issue, but disabling it solved the problem. Now, that would not be such an issue if my standard was higher than what my employer expected, but it would surely be a problem if my standard was lower. So 'this issue' or 'such an issue ' is correct here.